# Using Express module in Node js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the 'express' module of Node JS as per the example [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001808/ch02.html#I_sect12_d1e1886)

When I try and run the server and open 'localhost:8000',I get an error:

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
  at new View (/home/anr/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:41:42)
  at Function.app.render (/home/anr/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:486:12)
  at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/anr/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:798:7)
  at app.post.res.send.status (/home/anr/Desktop/node js/mvc/ntwitter.js:16:7)
  at callbacks (/home/anr/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
  at param (/home/anr/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
  at pass (/home/anr/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
  at Router._dispatch (/home/anr/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
  at Object.router (/home/anr/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
  at next (/home/anr/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
```

I have added the folder structure there,now the partials folder consists of:

```
chirps.html  index.html  styles.html  view0.html
```

view0 consists of the basic html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- There is a call to partial here-->
    <%- partial('partials/stylesheet', stylesheets) %>
    <title><%= title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= header %></h1>
    <%- body %>
  </body>
</html>
```

My code for the the index partial is here:

```
<form method="POST"  action="/send">
  <input type="text" length="140" name="tweet"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Tweet"/>
</form>
<%- partial('partials/chirp','tweets') %>
```

This is my chirps partial:

```
<p><%= chirps %></p>
```

This is my app.js:

```
var express=require('express');

//express gets http behind the scenes...
var app = express.createServer();
app.listen(8000);
var tweets=[];

//use http verbs instead of registering event listeners to http
//responds only to a get request...

app.get('/',function(req,res){

  //a conveniance method that does request headers,sends the message and ends the response
  //res.send('Welcome to Node Twitter');
  var title='Chirpie',
  header='Welcome To Chirpie';
  res.render('index', {
    locals:{
      'title':title,
      'header':header,
      'tweets':tweets,
      //'stylesheets':['public/style.css']
    }
  });
});

//the second argument in the post request is known as middleware
app.post('/send',express.bodyParser(),function(req,res){
  if(req.body && req.body.tweet) {
    tweets.push(req.body.tweet);
    if (acceptsHtml(req.headers['accept'])); {
      console.log('tweet recieved');
      res.redirect('/', 302); // the 302 status code indicates that this is not a permanent move
      //go to /send before redirecting every time
    }
  } else {  
    console.log('tweet recieved');
    res.send({ status: 'ok', message: 'tweet recieved' });
  } 
});

app.get('/tweets',function(req,res) {
  res.send(tweets);
});

function acceptsHtml(header) {
  var accepts=header.split(',');
  for(var i=0;i<accepts.length;i+=1) {
    if(accepts[i]==='text/html') return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

## EDIT:

Some issues that were fixed via comments:

```
1. Fixed `if (acceptsHtml(req.headers['accept']));`.Removed the semicolon there.
2.The files have to use `.ejs` unless the render specifies it as `.html` which requires the html module.Also move the `index.ejs` to `views`.
3.The reference to `chirp.ejs` was removed.Another point to note would be that the rendering engine is supposed to handle these calls now, the function `partial` no longer. exists,if you wish to use something like that use `include` instead.
```

So the code at the end of all this for the response of this route is:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
//a conveniance method that does request headers,sends the message and ends the response
//res.send('Welcome to Node Twitter');
var title='Chirpie',
    header='Welcome To Chirpie';

    res.render('index',
        {
        locals:{
        'title':title,
        'header':header,
        'tweets':tweets,
        }
    });


   });
```

Comment: in the line `if (acceptsHtml(req.headers['accept'])); {` there is a semicolon ending the statement, which is not correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have EJS views, but you never told Express that, so it's clueless about how to render them.

After `app = express.createServer()`, add this:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: I installed ejs,moved index.html to views,it throws this [error](http://pastebin.com/Znvb54He)

Comment: @user2309862: It might be looking for `index.ejs` rather than `index.html`.

Comment: @user2309862 If you don't specify the extension (`res.render('index.html')`), Express will assume the extension is the name of the view engine (`res.render('index'); // index.ejs`).

Comment: Using index.ejs,because I dont have the html module.Now,it says [partial is not defined](http://pastebin.com/qTvR9phD)

Comment: @user2309862 `res.partial()` and `partial()` were [removed from the API](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x#view-system-changes) with the release of Express 3.0. The expectation now is that view engines [will manage relationships](http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/) between views itself: https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs#layouts.